# Problemas al actualizar plugins de WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Os cuento, me dispuse a actualizar todos los plugins de mi WordPress de golpe. En medio de la actualización la página detuvo la carga y ahora, cada vez que intento acceder tanto a la web principal como al panel de administración, me sale el siguiente mensaje:

**No disponible temporalmente por un mantenimiento programado. Vuelve a comprobarlo en unos minutos.**

Me encuentro bloqueado, ¿qué debo hacer ahora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo haría sería acceder al sistema de archivos de tu wordpress (por ejemplo vía FTP o vía gestor de archivos que te proporcione tu hosting).

Buscar la carpeta de Plugins (generalmente: public_html/wp-content/plugins)

Descargar todos los plugins en tu equipo y eliminarlos del servidor.

En este punto ya te debería funcionar la web (aunque como no tienes plugins, la verás rara)

Luego se trata de ir subiendo uno a uno los plugins de nuevo a la carpeta (public_html/wp-content/plugins) e ir comprobando que funcione la web. Así hasta encontrar el que se ha quedado a medias y causado el problema. Seguramente ese lo tendrás que volver a descargar e instalar de cero.

Suerte!